# Capturing specific output from Expect script

Tags: php, telnet, expect, tasklist

I am trying to determine whether the application RA-POS is running on a remote Windows XP from a Mac using Expect. I send this through a PHP page hoping to return the result on that page as an initial test. Unfortunately when I run them all in conjunction the result is the command line prompt, not the actual information about whether the programs is running. Eventually I would like to create a conditional where expect returns a value of 1 or 0 based on whether RA-POS is running and then either continue to another script or stops the process.

Here's the Expect

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -d

set login "administrator"
set password "password"
set machineid [lindex $argv 0]
set portid [lindex $argv 1]
set cmdprompt "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>"
set output $expect_out(0,string)

spawn telnet -l administrator $machineid.noerrpole.com $portid
expect "password:"
send "$password\r"
expect "$cmdprompt"
send "tasklist /nh /FI \"IMAGENAME eq RA-POS.exe\"\r"
expect -re "(INFO:*)\r"
send_user "$expect_out(0,string)\n"
expect "$cmdprompt"
send "exit\r"
interact
```

Here's the PHP

```
<?php
echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";
echo "<title>Turn off Windows Automatic Update</title>";
echo "</head>";
echo "<body>";
echo '<img src="NOERRlogofinal.jpg">';
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<pre>";

$portoffset = 1000 * $_POST["station"];
$port = 21023 + $portoffset;
$mall = $_POST["mall"];

$cmd = "/usr/bin/expect /home/dev/www/RAPOStest " . $_POST["mall"] . " " . $port;


echo "Running " . $cmd;

$retval = system($cmd);
echo "<br>";
echo "sss <br>";
echo "$retval";
echo "sss <br>";




echo "</pre>";

echo "<br>Your POS has been updated " . $_POST["mall"];
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
```

And here's the output...

```
Running /usr/bin/expect /home/dev/www/RAPOStest NPCO-CP 22023spawn telnet -l administrator NPCO-CP.noerrpole.com 22023
Trying 166.161.172.106...

Connected to NPCO-CP.noerrpole.com.

Escape character is '^]'.

Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Service 


password: 

*===============================================================
Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Server.
*===============================================================
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>tasklist /nh /FI "IMAGENAME eq RA-POS.exe"
INFO: No tasks running with the specified criteria.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>password:

sss 
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>password:sss 

Your POS has been updated NPCO-CP
```

Comment: You're missing lots of quotes from your `echo`s. All `echo` calls should have quotes around them, unless `echo`ing a variable.

Comment: New to the website sorry, all the quotes are actually there, the code has been updated.